# Remove letters from a given string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

So my homework assignment is to remove initials of a given name, from a given string, using user inputs to define the variables. As I run the script below, it only registers one name.

```
def removeChar(initials, string):
    initials = initials
    string = string
    for char in initials:
        modified = string.replace(char, "")
    print modified
    return modified



def getInitials(name, string):
    initials = ""
    for i in name.lower().split():
        initials += i[0]
    print initials
    removeChar(initials, string)



def main():
    name = raw_input("What is your name? \n")
    string = raw_input("What string would you like to remove your initials from? \n")
    getInitials(name, string)
```

This is the output:

```
What is your name? 
John Doe
What string would you like to remove your initials from? 
Arjajbian Ndigdhts

Arjajbian Nights
```

Why wouldn't it remove the first initial?

Comment: Just a tip: `string = string` and `initials = initials` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Granted it's been awhile since I've used Python, but have you tried removing the space between names then making an array based off of characters?

Comment: Also, `string` is part of the Python standard library...

Comment: @JackManey As long as he has not imported `string` and overwrote the name, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @KevinFischer That's exactly what is being attempted here.

Comment: for the initials, i got them through the user input of John Doe

Comment: it removed the second initial, but not the first

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i thought so, but it didn't seem right.  I like your answer.  I can't write Python right now.  It would take awhile.

Comment: @KevinFischer Also, no need to make an array of "characters" since strings are already indexable. Strings are immutable sequences in Python. You can iterate over them out of the box.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as you can tell, I write more in C#.

Comment: @KevinFischer yeah, I always like to extoll the virtues of Python... ;)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I always try to read these types of questions.  you can almost always learn something new, or a refresher!  thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
modified = string.replace(char, "")
```

You are always using `replace` on the original string, so it removes each individual character from the original string and returns a new one. Just use `string = string.replace(char, "")`

Or else your function will always return a string that is the original string with the *last* initial removed.

Comment: thank you, this fixed it, i will mark it the answer when it allows me

Answer (score 0):

While @juanpa.arrivillaga has pointed out your problem, there is a much more Pythonic way to remove the characters `j` and `d` from your input string; Using a [*generator expression*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
>>> input_str = "Arjajbian Ndigdhts"
>>> ''.join(c for c in input_str if c.lower() not in 'jd')
'Arabian Nights'
>>>
```

This works by iterating through `input_str` and only passing the characters to `''.join()` which are *not* `j` or `d`.

Comment: @EshChhura Sure thing. Just something to think on ;-) I also included a link to a page about _generator expression_ if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need the

```
 initials = initials
    string = string
```

as this does nothing your telling to make this variable the same as it is already
Also
I think it is this

```
modified = string.replace(char, "")
```

you make this create a variable called `modified` but later on in the code you are saying to get `String` and not `modified`
either change `String to modified` apart from in the top def or change the `modified to string` and then it will work hopefully